Using Parseval's Theorem to Evaluate a Sum
Question: assume that $f(x)$ is a periodic function with period $T=2L=2\pi$ and is defined on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. use Parseval's theorem to calculate the following sums:
$$
\begin{gather} 
\displaystyle \large 
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x(\pi-x)\,\,\,\text{if}:0\le x\le \pi \\ \\
x(\pi+x)\,\,\,\text{if}:-\pi \le x \le 0
\end{cases} \\ \\
\large \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{960}\;\;,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}
\end{gather}
$$
(edit: for clarification, the sums in the question are not a given it has to be found with the use of Parseval's theorem)
My Work: this is what I've done so far:
$$
\begin{gather}
\large \displaystyle 
a_{0}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[ \int_{0}^{\pi}x(\pi-x)\,\text{d}x +\int_{-\pi}^{0} x(\pi+x)\,\text{d}x \right]=0
\end{gather}
$$
and we can argue that:
$$
\begin{gather}
\displaystyle \large 
a_{0}=\frac{\langle{f,C_{0}}\rangle }{\langle{C_{0},C_{0}}\rangle }=0 \\ \\
\displaystyle \large \Longrightarrow
a_{n}=\frac{\langle{f,C_{n}}\rangle }{\langle{C _{n},C_{n}}\rangle } =0
\end{gather}
$$
and
$$
\begin{gather}
\displaystyle \large b_{n}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin (nx)\,\text{d}x
\\ \\ \displaystyle \large 
=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi}x(\pi-x)\sin(nx)\,\text{d}x}_{\textstyle I_{1}}  +\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{0}x(\pi+x)\sin(nx)\,\text{d}x}_{\textstyle I_{2}}\right] \\ \\
\xrightarrow[\displaystyle \cos n\pi=(-1)^n]{\textstyle \text{integration by parts}} 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \large I_{1}=\frac{2}{n^3}(1-(-1)^n) \\ \\ \\
\displaystyle \large I_{2}=\frac{2}{n^3}(1-(-1)^n)
\end{cases} \\ \\
\displaystyle \large
b_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}(I_{1}+I_{2})=\frac{4}{\pi n^3}(1-(-1)^n)
\end{gather}
$$
therefore the fourier series approximation of $f(x)$ will be:
$$
\begin{gather}
\displaystyle \large f(x)\approx \widetilde{f}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\pi n^3} \sin(nx)
\end{gather}
$$
according to Parseval's theorem if $f(x)$ is a periodic piecewise continuous function with period $T=2L$ we can write:
$$
\begin{gather}
\displaystyle \large a_{0}^2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2+b_{n}^2=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{T} f^2(x)\,\text{d}x
\end{gather}
$$
we can shift the bounds from $[0,T]$ to $[-T/2,T/2]$ so we can use our original $f(x)$:
$$
\begin{gather}
\displaystyle \large 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{32}{\pi^2 n^6}(1-(-1)^n)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x)\,\text{d}x \\ \\
\displaystyle \large =\frac{1}{\pi}\left[ \int_{0}^\pi x^2(\pi-x)^2\,\text{d}x+\int_{-\pi}^0 x^2(\pi+x)^2\,\text{d}x \right]=\frac{\pi^4}{15} \\ \\ 
\displaystyle \large
\Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{480} 
\end{gather}
$$
this is where I get stuck, I don't know how to manipulate this to find the sums given in the problem initially.

notice that (assuming your calculations are correct)
$\large \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^6} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} - \frac{1}{2}*\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{{\pi}^6}{480}-\frac{{\pi}^6}{960} = \frac{{\pi}^6}{960}$

thanks for your answer, can you please elaborate on this part of the answer $$\displaystyle \large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^6}$$

@illestboi If you remove the even numbers from the natural numbers you're left with the odd numbers.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^{2n}}{(2n)^6}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^6}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}$$

Thanks for your reply but as you can see from the question I have to find this sum $$\displaystyle \large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^6}$$ I don't get how this sum is related to your answer, I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate more on this
